# Three.js CSS3D Renderer - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the CSS3d renderer to work, and it seems like basic Javascript is hindering me.

I load all the Three.js libraries separately via Sid.js, and if I add the CSS3DRenderer.js file via this method, I get

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on `renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();`

(it is being loaded after the Three.js library)

If I load it from the header, I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

(cssrender line 6)

I'm using this as an example http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

Any ideas how I can get the CSS3d renderer to load?

EDIT

Here is an example http://gms.beektest.co/g150

The file where all the scripts get loaded via Sid.js is http://gms.beektest.co/resources/js/player.js

```
Sid.js([  
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r67/three.min.js",
            "../../resources/js/beekjs/three-css3d.min.js",
            "../../resources/js/beekjs/Detector.js",
            "../../resources/js/beekjs/beek.js",
            "../../resources/js/beekjs/tween.min.js",
            "../../resources/js/beekjs/scene.js"],

            function(){
            showProgress(0.4);
            init();
        }
    );
```

The renderer function that calls the error is

```
    renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer(); (error is on this line)
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: Can you upload your files somewhere or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you don't use Sid.js do you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the css3d library and three.js to the header fixed it.  Will have to work out another way of loading it dynamically.